# Edit URL in browser for unmatched controller-action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written following method in my Global.asax file which redirects me to default controller-action if I enter any inappropriate URL.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();
            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
                {
                    case 404:
                        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Info");
                        routeData.Values.Add("action", "person");                          
                        Server.ClearError();
                        IController infoController = new InfoController();
                        infoController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
                        break;
                }
            }            
        }
```

If I enter URL as `http://localhost:2032/asjjsjdj`, it redirects me to `person` action in `Info` controller but displays URL as it is. It should also display URL as `http://localhost:2032/Info/person`. Please let me know how do I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change URL in browser you can use [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx) but before you have to [ClearError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.clearerror(v=vs.110).aspx) to prvent mvc to handle the error:

```
...
switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
{
    case 404:
        HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home/Contact");
        break;
}
...
```